# Tensorflow JS & Electron Forge - Error importing tensorflow js after npm run make

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, electron, electron-forge

I have built this little app with tensorflow js. I can run it perfectly on Windows 10 using the `npm start`, however after I successfully run `npm run make` it becomes impossible to import tensorflow. I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: The specified module could not be found. \\?\C:\Users\teste\AppData\Local\my-app\app-1.0.0\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node
    at process.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1016)
    at Object.func (electron/js2c/asar.js:140)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:149)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:728)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:853)
```

When I go down to `C:\Users\teste\AppData\Local\my-app\app-1.0.0\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\@tensorflow\tfjs-node\lib\napi-v5\tfjs_binding.node` the file is there and perfectly accessible

I'm running windows 10, node `v12.13.0`, electron `8.2.1` with electron forge

My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "productName": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My Electron application description",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "publish": "electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "echo \"No linting configured\"",
    "install": "electron-rebuild --pre-gyp-fix"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "guzeda",
  "license": "MIT",
  "config": {
    "forge": "./forge.config.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.5.1",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^1.5.1",
    "electron-reload": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "face-api.js": "^0.22.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.0.0-beta.50",
    "electron": "8.2.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.10.1"
  }
}
```

My forge.config is:

```
module.exports = {
    makers: [
        {
            name: '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel',
            config: {
                name: "my-app"
            }
        }
    ],
    plugins: [
        ['@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives']
    ],
    packagerConfig:{asar:true}
}
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: does this tf contains executables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the solution. That happened because the dll needs to be in the same folder as the buddings. The error message was very misleading.

At the end it was necessary to write some post install script to copy the correct dll to the folder and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just double checked your code - was to do with your folder structure.

Why are you using tensorflow.js instead of python et al, if i may ask?

Comment: It does not concern to my folder structure

It is just that electron forge wen package my application it puts all the binaries of the native dependencies (tensorflow)  into `app.asar.unpacked` folder but it doesn't copy the dll with it.

My solution was really simple: I'm packing the dll separately in a .zip and all the time the app lunches it checks if the dll is in the correct folder and unzip it from the asar source if not

I'm using Node because the Users PCs are very low end so python consumes too much memory (I tested) and I'm not really well versed in Java or C++